# Norm of covariance and precision matrices: is there any meaning?

Tags: probability, covariance

Let $\Sigma$ be a covariance matrix of some distribution. Then $\Sigma^{-1}$ is the precision matrix.

Question: Does $\|\Sigma\|$ or $\|\Sigma^{-1}\|$ have any meaning (for any norm, though I ask in particular for the spectral norm).?

Comment: The spectral norm is related to eigenvalues, which have to do with diagonalization, which corresponds to linear combinations of your random variables such that their covariance is zero for off diagonal pairs in the new basis. So there's some interpretation but I haven't thought it through 100%.

Answer (score 10):

Let $x$ be a random vector with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and let $e$ be a vector such that $||e||_2=1$. The projection of $x$ on $e$ is given by $(e^Tx)e$. Notice that $e^Tx$ can be considered as the coordinate of the projection along the direction given by $e$. Also notice that $Var(e^Tx) = e^T \Sigma e$. Since $\Sigma$ is positive semi-definite, the maximum of the above variance is obtained at $e^*$, which is the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda^*$, the maximum eigenvalue of $\Sigma$. Then $Var(e^{*T}x) = e^{*T} \Sigma e^* = \lambda^* e^{*T} e^* = \lambda^* = ||\Sigma||_2$.

That is, $e^*$ is the direction such that the projection of $x$ on it reaches the maximum variance. $||\Sigma||_2$ is the maximized variance. Principal component analysis (PCA) is based on the above.

Comment: Good answer, but I am actually more interested in the precision matrix case.